# Importing module to VS code

Tags: python, python-module

im very new in programming and i learn Python.
I'm coding on mac btw.
I'd like to know how can i import some modules in VS code.

For exemple, if i want to use the speedtest module i have to download it (what i did) and then import it to my code. But it never worked and i always have the error no module etc.

I used pip to install each package, i have them on my computer but i really don't know to import them on VS code. Even with the terminal of the IDE.

I know it must be something very common for u guys but i will help me a lot.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick Summary

This might not be an issue with VS Code.

**Problem:** The folder to which `pip3` installs your packages is not on your `$PATH`.

**Fix:** Go to `/Applications/Python 3.8` in Finder, and run the `Update Shell Profile.command` script. Also, if you are using `pip install <package>`, instead of `pip3 install <package>` *that might be your problem*.

## Details

Your Mac looks for installed packages in several different folders on your Mac. The list of folders it searches is stored in an environment variable called `$PATH`. Paths like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin` should be in the `$PATH` environment variable, since that's where `pip3` installs all  packages.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have multiple versions of python on your computer.

You have to select your python interpreter for which you have installed those packages using pip to do this you'll have to click on the python version you see in the bottom and select the correct interpreter from the list:
[image]

You can also find more information within the VSCode [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter).

Comment: Yes, my mistake was to always select the latest version of python but as you pointed out it was the wrong one. thanks a lot